# SQL - left join generate duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates, left-join

I have code to select some applications but LEFT JOIN is creating duplicates.

Question: How to get rid of duplicates generated by

```
LEFT JOIN
    attachments as att
ON 
    (a.ssn = att.ssn AND att.doc_type = 'id_copy' AND att.source = 'cpt3')
```

My Work:

I am considering **SELECT DISTINCT** or **GROUP BY** but, can't figure out where to put them.

This is the query:

```
SELECT
        a.*, c.code, l.who, l.locked_time, att.id AS attnew, 
        ( SELECT 
            COUNT(*) 
          FROM 
            applications as a2 
          WHERE 
            a2.approved = 'Y' 
          AND 
            a2.paid = 'Y' 
          AND 
            a2.paid_back = 'Y' 
          AND 
            a2.ssn = a.ssn 
        ) AS previous_apps
    FROM 
        applications as a
    LEFT JOIN 
        locked_by as l 
    USING(id) 
    LEFT JOIN 
        campaign_codes as c 
    ON 
        c.id = a.campaign
    LEFT JOIN
        attachments as att
    ON 
        (a.ssn = att.ssn AND att.doc_type = 'id_copy' AND att.source = 'cpt3')
    WHERE 
        a.closed='N' 
    AND 
        a.paid = 'N' 
    ORDER BY 
        a.arrived_date 
    DESC
```

Comment: There are currently approx 2636 questions under the SQL tag about `JOIN` and duplicate rows. It's hard to imagine that this isn't a duplicate of at least one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

to avoid duplicates. In your case:

```
...
    WHERE 
        a.closed='N' 
    AND 
        a.paid = 'N' 
    GROUP BY
        a.id
    ORDER BY 
        a.arrived_date 
    DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an one to one relation to avoid duplicates and `att.id` is the same for each `att.ssn` or you need only one (MAX,MIN,..ANY?) `att.id`. Try this:

```
LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT ssn,
                MAX(id) as id,
           FROM attachments 
           WHERE doc_type = 'id_copy' AND source = 'cpt3'
           GROUP BY ssn
         )as att
    ON 
        (a.ssn = att.ssn)
```